# filter on Flux object structure

Tags: java, spring, functional-programming, reactive, react-functional-component

I have one object structure in flux looks like

```
Flux<someResponse>  someResponse
```

and some responses is like this

```
public class someResponse {
    private List<Task> tasks;
}
```

and task object contain taskID

Now my job is filter out on taskid , say if any task id found like 2001 then return true else false.

But I am not able to write in proper java 8 way ... can any one help me out at this point

Way I was trying

```
(tasksResponses
    .toStream(tasks -> tasks.getTasks())).filter(eachtask -> eachtask.getTaskCode().equals(TASK_CODE));
```

but it did not work .....

please help me on this

Comment: Are you getting an exception? What does not work exactly?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? Keep in the list only the tasks with a given ID or remove from the list tasks that does not have a given ID?